# If $\lim a_n$ does not exist, then does this mean that $\lim a_n\neq 0$?

Tags: notation

> If $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ does not exist or if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$, then the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is divergent.
>
> *From Stewart's* Early Transcendentals *Calculus.*

I would think that if the the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ does not exist, then it would not equal zero. However, the inclusion that the limit also cannot be zero seems to tell me that I am wrong. In general, if some $a$ is undefined, non-existent, or not even a number, is it good notation to say that $a\neq0$?

Comment: The word between the two conditions is "or". You seem to be interpreting it as "and".

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq 0$ means that the limit exists and is not equal to zero. If the limit doesn't exist, the statement is meaningless; it's neither true nor false.

Comment: @JoeyZou I think you're misunderstanding the question (or maybe I am). I believe the question is if it would be enough to simply say "If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq 0$ then..." and simply leave out the part "If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ does not exist...". Essentially, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq 0$ covers the case where the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Eff The case when $(a_n)$ does not exist should not be considered as covered by the assertion that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\ne0$ since this assertion means 1. that the limit exists and 2. that it is not zero.

Comment: @Did I understand that :-). I just explained the meaning of the question (at least as I understand the question).

Comment: @Eff The trouble is that the sentence "Essentially, if limn→∞an≠0 covers the case where the limit does not exist" in your comment is squarely wrong.

Comment: @Did Exactly. I rephrased the question, I did not answer it. I agree that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq 0$ does *not* cover the case where the limit does not exist, but I didn't want to answer the question in the comments.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan why would lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty} \neq 0$ not be true or false if the limit did not exist? That statement is true if the limit $is$ $not$ $zero$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Tell me is this statement true, "If $n$ is both even and odd, then $n$ = 17".

Comment: @Prince: that statement is vacuously true. It is not an example of the phenomenon I'm describing. An example is "brown squared equals $17$." This statement is meaningless, and not true or false, because I have not specified what it means to square a color.

Comment: @PrinceM However, this is different from what I have asked. I have some $x$, and I want to know whether or not saying that $x\neq0$ also implicates that $x$ has the possibility of being undefined or non-existent. No number can be both even and odd, so your statement can be written, "if **FALSE**, then _n_ = 17", which really cannot be said without predicate logic, because we are unsure of what $n$ equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I wrote something meaningless and terrible such as

$\sqrt{\mathbb R} + 27 \ne 13 \implies $

$\sqrt{\mathbb R} \ne -14 \implies $

$\mathbb R \ne 196$

Your assumption ought to be that I clearly don't have the foggiest idea what I'm talking about and I am clearly ... lost.

Then supposed I argued "But every statement is true!  $\sqrt{\mathbb R}$ is a meaningless expression so it isn't an number and so we can not add 27 to it and we wouldn't get 13 if we did that!  So it *doesn't* equal 13 because it doesn't mean anything."

Well, technically I may be right but I should be banned from teaching for lack of clarification.

$\lim a_n \ne 0$ implies *very* strongly that $\lim a_n$ is a well-defined value which, although it doesn't equal 0, does equal something else.

Maybe I can quibble $\lim a_n $ diverging $\implies \lim a_n \ne 0$ but no-one can claim that isn't misleading.

At any rate "If $a_n$ diverges then $\sum a_n$ diverges, and if $\lim a_n \ne 0$ then $\sum a_n$ diverges" $\iff$ "If $a_n$ diverges  or $\lim a_n \ne 0$ then $\sum a_n$ diverges" $\iff$ "If $\lim a_n \ne 0$ or $a_n$ diverges then $\sum a_n$ diverges" are all equivalent and true statements.  Even if a nitpicker might quibble they are redundant.  So what?  Redundancy is perfectly acceptable.

Especially if it aids clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, to answer your question, if the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ does not exist, it makes no sense to say that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, where $a$ does not exist.  We would say that the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is *divergent*.  In short, no, it is not good notation to say that $a\neq 0$, in any of the cases you stated.

Secondly, the theorem is stating two separate conditions for the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ to be divergent .  It could be just as easily (and perhaps less confusingly) have been stated as two separate theorems:

> If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ does not exist, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is divergent.

and

> If $\lim\limits _{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is divergent.

These are two different situations, with no overlap.  I think this is where the confusion arises.

Comment: That is to say, $a \neq 0$ means that $a$ necessarily exists. (?)

Comment: Lim of sin(x) as x --> infinity. It does not equal 0 and it does not exist. @RobertZhang

Comment: Furthermore, saying $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$ (or a continuous analogue) does not imply equality in the traditional sense.  It is simply a notation used to mean that the terms of the sequence (or values of the function) approach that value as the index gets larger.